# How to linear approximate a function of 3 variables.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the approximation to $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ at the point $(3,2,6)$

The tangent plane to the surface is the approximation, so the normal to the tangent plane is given by $\nabla f$, I worked the normal out, so I have a normal vector and a point so this defines a plane. So lets say $\nabla f = (a,b,c)$ at $(3,2,6)$then the tangent plane should be $a(x-3) + b(y-2) + c(z-6)$ However after working this out I did not get the correct answer, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: At $(x,y,z)=(3,2,6)$, the plane should match the function. But your plane equation gives $0$ at that point, which is not $f(3,2,6)$. What's missing?

Comment: I have to add f(3,2,6)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Compare to linear approximation in one dimension near the point $x=x_0$: $f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$.